# Ajax Error when Including related data EF Core

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core-2.2, entity-framework-core-2.2

Here are my models

```
  [Table(name: "hListasAbastecimento")]
    public class ListaAbastecimento
    {
        public ListaAbastecimento()
        {
            DataCriacao = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public ListaAbastecimento(string uap, int colaboradorId)
        {
            UAP = uap;
            ColaboradorId = colaboradorId;
            DataCriacao = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ColaboradorId { get; set; }   
        [ForeignKey("ColaboradorId")]
        public virtual Colaborador Colaborador { get; set; }

        public string UAP { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ReferenciaAbastecimento> Referencias { get; set; }
    }

 [Table(name: "hReferenciasAbastecimento")]
    public class ReferenciaAbastecimento
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(15)]
        public string Referencia { get; set; }
        public int? QtdAbastecimento { get; set; }
        public int? QtdCaixas { get; set; }
        public int? QtdPecasPorCaixa { get; set; }

        public int ListaAbastecimentoId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ListaAbastecimentoId")]
        public ListaAbastecimento ListaAbastecimento { get; set; }
    }
```

here is ajax call

```
       $.ajax({
            url: "/Account/Abastecimentos/Index?handler=Abastecimentos",
            type: "GET",                
            success: function (response) {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
```

and here is page method

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAbastecimentosAsync()
    {
        var abastecimentosList = await _context.ListasAbastecimento
            .Include(la => la.Referencias)
            .ToListAsync();

        return new JsonResult(abastecimentosList);
    }
```

I managed to find out that the error came from including Referencias, which means if I do this it works

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAbastecimentosAsync()
    {
        var abastecimentosList = await _context.ListasAbastecimento
            .ToListAsync();

        return new JsonResult(abastecimentosList);
    }
```

First, I thought it was not working cause of virtual on the model but I tried removing and the error still happened.

I can run the query in SQL fine with a simple select and join and I can get all the data...

**UPDATE**

OK, for some reason this does not give me an exception. Usually it would show a server side exception something about circular reference exception when loading certain entities directly from context to JSON. except this time the only thing it showed me was an uncompleted json.

I ended up mapping up to view model to avoid the circular reference problem of navigation properties

```
 try
        {

            var abastecimentosList = await _context.ListasAbastecimento
                .Include(la => la.Colaborador)
                .Include(la => la.Referencias)
                .ToListAsync();

            var list = _mapper.Map<List<ListaAbastecimento>, List<ListaAbastecimentoViewModel>>(abastecimentosList);


            return new JsonResult(list);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
```

this triggers the ajax success function now. So basically the problem is why the exception was not triggered besides returning a bad json.

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: that's what i can't find out, i tried using try catch and it does not trigger it

Comment: In which case check the status code and response text in the network tab of dev tools in your browser. There should be an error message to help you debug in there

Comment: it returns 200 but i think i know what is the error. It must be about that circular exception from json cause when i load referencias, i can access ListaAbastecimentos from it which means it keeps going and going if i'm not wrong but it used to give me exception unlike this time. Either way, i am mapping everything to view models to test it

Comment: I prefer the view model approach, however, if you really wanted you could add this to the configure services method:

`services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);`

Comment: Yeah in the end i find the View Model approach much cleaner and safer rather than just ignoring the problem.